# Add 2, or 4 or even more short values at once

Tags: x86, sse, simd

Is there any instruction in modern CPU to add (for example) 4 `short` (16 bit) values at once and store it in one `int` value (32 bit)? These 4 values are placed in sequential, and can be aligned to any block size.

Comment: Do you count vector instructions as well? Yes - there should be one. Note that four consecutive bytes are exactly the same thing as one dword (up to interpretation)

Comment: Are you just interested in x86 or in any architecture with SIMD ? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: I wanna call .dll code from C#. It can be anything like SIMD or something. Oldest CPU which I wanna support is core2duo. If CPU doesnt suport simd etc. I just call other function in managed code.

Comment: OK - I've re-tagged for you now as the question was not very clear or specific in its original form.

Comment: This would have been easy if you were summing bytes..

Comment: Yea, but I need to sum short values that represent audio smaples.

Comment: Could you give a slightly higher level overview of what you're doing? If you're summing an entire array of shorts, for example, you could `paddw` most of them and you'd only have a tricky part once at the end. Bit of a lame example I suppose, and I don't mean to be offensive, but I don't know what your SSE skill level is..

Comment: Well I was tired when I asked this question. Now I see I thought everything wrong. I tried to quick render audio wave form. But I forgot I need to compute positive and negative values separately. So no SSE optimization will help here. Anyway: you got short[] myArray, now u need to compute int positiveSum and int negativeSum. Also find max and min sample in array. In c# its easy, but when you have 1GB audio array, it takes a while even in unmanaged code.

Comment: That doesn't sound that impossible in SSE to me, a little trickier sure.. but certainly possible. Just takes a couple of shifts (to convert signed words to signed dwords and to make a mask of negative elements) and some masking. And getting the maximum and minimum are pretty easy with SSE.

Comment: Tell me where to find opcodes about min and max for good begining :)

Comment: `pmaxsw` and `pminsw`, you can find them and other vector instructions in AMD Manual Volume 4: http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/26568_APM_v4.pdf the min and max won't be hard (the only special thing is that you'd need some `psrldq`'s at the end for the horizontal part), I could do the summation thingy but it wouldn't fit here as an answer to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that exactly matches your requirements AFAIK - for x86 (SSE) the closest would probably be [pmaddwd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k87x524b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vcref_mm_madd_epi16) (`_mm_madd_epi16()`) (with a multiplier of 1).

Comment: Well I asked bad question, but anyway your answer will be helpful for me in differents cases of my application :)