# Is there any instruction to add all bytes in an MMX register?

Tags: x86, addition, mmx

I need to calculate the sum of the 4 integers I have inside a MMX register. For example, I have this MMX register:
[image]
And I want to get this result (I don't mind if it's in the same register or if it's in a normal one):
[image]

I want to know if there is an instruction that performs that operation. I'm using x86 assembly in windows.
My first guess is to put 4 `1` in another MMX register and call `PMADDWD` so that I end up with [X1+X2][X3+X4] but I think that's quite dirty.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are X1, X2, X3, X4 really all different widths or is that just a problem with the diagram ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a really good drawer. They are all the same length

Comment: OK - and another question, do you really mean MMX (64 bit SIMD) or are you talking about SSE (128 bit SIMD) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add 2, or 4 or even more short values at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131883/add-2-or-4-or-even-more-short-values-at-once)

Comment: Use `psadbw` against a zeroed register to get a horizontal sum of unsigned bytes.  (Your question *title* says bytes, but you seem to be working with 16-bit words so it's not clear.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PMADDWD` is actually quite a good way of summing - even though you are "wasting" a multiply operation by using a multiplicand of 1, you get the widening (unpacking) operation for free, so you're getting quite a lot of value out of a single instruction.

Comment: Ok, so I understand that the instruction I'm looking for doesn't exist. Another thing, once I have it as [X1+X2][X3+X4], is there a way to access the Higher section as a dword? At the moment I'm moving the lower one to a register and then shifting to the right with `psrlq mm2,32`

Comment: Sorry - I only really use SSE, not MMX - you might want to post another question about this if you cant find anything suitable.